# Sanity CMS custom sorting

Tags: javascript, fetch, sanity

I don’t know if exists some way to sorting the results by custom field.
My query:

```sh
 *[_type == "movies" && actors]
{
   ..., 
   isHarryMovie: name match "Harry*" 
}
```

So I want to sort the results by `isHarry`, is it posible?

I tried something like this:

```sh
 *[_type == "movies" && actors] | order(isHarryMovie asc)
{
   ..., 
   isHarryMovie: name == "Harry" 
}
```

and

```
 *[_type == "movies" && actors] | order("isHarryMovie" asc)
{
   ..., 
   isHarryMovie: name == "Harry" 
}
```

but they didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order after projecting:

```
*[_type == "movies"] {
  ..., 
  isHarryMovie: name match "Harry*" 
} | order(isHarryMovie desc)
```

This will sort by the `isHarryMovie` attribute that you added to each document.

But this kind of query will be forced to load all the movies, then filter, and then sort — it won't be fast. You're probably better off sorting by score:

```
*[_type == "movies"] | score(name match "Harry*") | order(_score desc)
```

This will assign a high score to any movie with `name match "Harry*"`, and a low score to everything else.